# is it safe to drop an innodb table to free up disk space

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have an innodb table with  Innodb_file_per_table set to on. I want to free up disk space (because I am running out of room). One of my history tables can be deleted totally and recreated fresh from a mysqldump of just the table structure. The history.idb file is 79 GB. 
my question is, if i drop table `history` will it also delete the .frm and .idb files or will I have to do that manually? Also, is this safe? I know some transactions like `optimize` and `truncate` actually create a temporary table. I don't have room on and of the drives for that.  Also, i need to run this on a production machine. Will this lock things up for very long? 
thanks for any help

Comment: If you drop a table, you won't be able to get data back unless you have some data backup. If you are okay with that, then deleting should free up your space, you don't have to do it manually.

Comment: You can also `TRUNCATE TABLE history` which will replace it with a new, empty tablespace. The difference is the table will still appear in `SHOW TABLES` and it will have the same columns and everything, but it will have zero rows of data, and no index entries. It will take almost no storage space until you fill it with data again.

Answer (score 2):

Do `DROP TABLE history`.  Do not do anything manually with the files; it will lead to trouble later.

The `DROP` removes the `.frm` and the `.ibd` (in the case of "file_per_table").  It also removes knowledge of the table from `ibdata1`, which is otherwise unchanged.

Comment: so dropping the table will also delete the .idb file and the .frm file?  Loosing data is ok, i have it all backed up on an archive server.